# Как импортировать содержимое заголовочных файлов?

Tags: c++, c

Есть yasnippet-inc, который добавляет includ'ы.
https://github.com/kohn/yasnippet-inc
Можно ли сделать так,чтобы добавлялись нужные includ'ы заголовочных файлов(например,классов),которые лежат в той же папке?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, одна директива препроцессора позволяет подключить только один файл. Но вы можете сделать следующим образом. Создайте дополнительный файл (можно без расширения) и в нём подключите все нужные файлы. Например:

**SuperHeader**

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "file3.h"
```

А в остальных файлах вы можете подключать только **SuperHeader**:

```
#include "SuperHeader"
```